# Oracle Query combining Two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have two tables. I want to combine this tables to get the results like below:

Table_1

```
RegNo       Class_id    Name    Address
------------------------------------------------
ABC/R/13-14-1       1   Name1   Address1
ABC/R/13-14-2       2   Name1   Address1
ABC/R/2014-15-1     1   Name1   Address1
ABC/R/2014-15-2     3   Name1   Address1
ABC/R/13-14-3       1   Name1   Address1
------------------------------------------------
```

Table_2

```
Class_id    Class
----------------------
1       IA
2       IB
3       IC
----------------------
```

i need the result like:

```
Class   2013    2014
--------------------
IA  2   1
IB  1   0
IC  0   1
--------------------
```

I am using Group by to get the results in a separately for each year, but I am not able to get the year in column-wise format like the requirement. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the part of the RegNo after `ABC/R/` supposed to be the date?  Please show the query you have so far.

Comment: No, its like 13-14 and 2014-15. I am using the following query, but its not giving the needed result:                                                                    select  a.class_category_id,count(*) from m_vendor_hdr a,m_class b
where a.CLASS_CATEGORY_ID=b.class_id and a.vendor_registration_number like 'APW%13-14%' group by a.CLASS_CATEGORY_ID;

Comment: does Table_1 have a regular date field for the Class creation or Class joining or something like that? Since that would be faster as a like statement shown below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If condition you used in your query works for your data then you can use this query:

```
select t2.class, 
    sum(case when regno like 'ABC%13-14%' then 1 else 0 end) c2013,
    sum(case when regno like 'ABC%14-15%' then 1 else 0 end) c2014
  from table_1 t1
  join table_2 t2 on t1.class_id = t2.class_id
  group by t2.class
```

Output:

```
CLASS      C2013      C2014
----- ---------- ----------
IA             2          1
IB             1          0
IC             0          1
```